# Write update sql script in migration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity for the Landlord.
Here is the model:

```
[Required]
    [MaxLength(PM101Consts.MaxNameLength)]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(PM101Consts.MaxNameLength)]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(PM101Consts.MaxCompanyNumberLength)]
    public virtual string CompanyNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(PM101Consts.MaxVatNumberLength)]
    public virtual string VatNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int LandlordTypeId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(PM101Consts.MaxCompanyNameLength)]
    public virtual string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(PM101Consts.MaxWebsiteLength)]
    public virtual string Website { get; set; }

    public long? UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
```

I create a User table with those properties:

```
public virtual string Name { get; set; }

public virtual string Surname { get; set; }

public virtual string Email { get; set; }

public virtual string Password { get; set; }
```

And I need to create Users for all Landlords, that already created in the database. I need to do this in-migration. So `User.Name = Landlord.FirstName` , `User.Surname = Landlord.LastName`,
`User.Email = Landlord.Email`. How I need to write a script.

Answer (score 0):

you can seed data like following example

```
protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
{
   var landlords = context.Landlord.ToList();

   foreach(var landlord in loandlords){
     var user = new Users(){
         Name = landlord.FirstName,
         Surname = landlord.LastName,
         Email = landlord.Email
   }
   context.Users.Add(user); 
}

    base.Seed(context);
}
```

Comment: Okay. Can I run this seed in migration?

And I guess it's better to make update script

Comment: It will run when you run your application

Comment: Or you can use this sql script                                                                                 ``` INSERT INTO Users (Name,Surname,Email ) (SELECT FirstName as 'Name',LastName as 'Surname',Email from Landlords) ```